# Can I run Pi-hole and other applications at the same time on one pi?

Tags: pi-3, pi-hole

I never had a Pi before and want to get me a pi-hole for my network.
Is it possible to run pi-hole on a pi and some other applications like:

- That one that emulates chromecast? MiracleCast?
- Something that    emulates a smarttv and let me stream
  YouTube/netflix or just from a normal web browser?
- Or just something that lets me stream Video    files/streams from my
  pc with an application other than miraclecast?

The pi would be connected via Ethernet cable with the Network and with HDMI with the tv.

Comment: Welcome. We avoid "can it be done" questions that are this vague. Is it possible? Yes it is possible to run multiple apps on a RPi.

Comment: It sure is possible. My Pi-Hole is also running a node-red dashboard, an iptables firewall and an openvpn server.

Comment: Thanks for the Info. I just read, like Doncho wrote it in his answere, that some applications need a whole os Image and I thougt that this will prevent me from installing more than one app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run any number of apps you want on the PI, as long as you have free RAM, disk space and CPU time. The tricky part will be getting all of them installed and configured to your liking.

The easiest way to run something on your PI is to download an OS image. You obviously get only one app this way.

The other way is to install a base distribution (like Raspbian) and then install any number of applications.

Obviously the third way is to start with OS image with some app installed for you and then add the rest of the applications. The hardest thing to get running is a chromecast / MiracleCast "emulation".

I know of at least two distributions of [Kodi](https://kodi.wiki/view/Raspberry_Pi) and because it is really multiple applications configured together (hard to get right initially) I would recommend you to start with that. Once you have Kodi running to your liking make a backup of the SD card. After that try installing each and every additional app you like. If something breaks - restore the backup and try again :-) I am not familiar with [pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/), but it looks like you must download an installer and run it (most likely as root)... piece of cake. Luck!

Comment: ok thanks for this answere. I will try that as soon I buy my PI :) I think the PI model 3 B+ should be good for that job I guess?

Comment: PI 3 B+ is the most powerful of the PI family so far - if it does not do the job, no other PI would :-) Luck.